# Finding min and max elements in a float array using out params

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have written the function below:

```
void find_minmax_float(float * begin, float * end, 
                float ** min, float ** max) {
    if(begin == end) { //if it is not an array
        *min = *max = 0;
    } else { //if atleast 1 element exist
        *min = *max = begin;
        while(++begin != end) {
            if(*begin < ** min) *min = begin;
            if(*begin > ** max) *max = begin;
        }
    }
}
```

And I test it with the following code:

```
float floats[] = { 0.9, 1.11, 2.35, 5.999 };
int size = sizeof(floats) / sizeof(floats[0]);
float * fmin;
float * fmax;

find_minmax_float(floats, floats + size, &fmin, &fmax);
printf("float[]\tmin=%f\tmax=%f\n", *fmin, *fmax);
```

But I get this weird output on terminal:

```
float[] min=0.000000    max=5.999000
```

Obviously I get the `min` value not correct, while the `max` seems to be ok. I can not figure out what is going wrong! I should get `min=0.900000`

I tried 0.1 to 0.9 and I always get 0.000000 for the min.

Comment: Hmm - [works for me](http://ideone.com/GX2ryd) - what compiler are you using ?

Comment: @PaulR GCC 4.8.4   ok I will test this isolated (right now it is inside a huge pile of mess)

Comment: I would add debug output to dump all addresses used in `find_minmax_float()`.  Also, it would not hurt to print values for *begin, **min, and **max at the top of the `while` loop.

Comment: Works for me too. My guess is that *min or float[0] get corrupted due to some bug elsewhere in your big program.

Comment: Yes guys when I tested the code isolated it works as intended....for sure the problem is somewhere else. Thanks a lot for your effort on testing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fmin` and `fmax` are unitialized pointers. Your code just invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I should delete the question or not. Anyway, the problem was somewhere else in my code which apparently overwrote the first element in my array.

Thanks a lot to people who tested my code :P